# I can not configure out "red color" tag for ejs file in vscode

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, ejs

I am configuring node.js project in VScode.
I installed some packages for node project and react.

but when I added ejs template file, it shows me red color at the beginning tag "<%".

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHsi3.png)

I want to make it perfect. it looks bad.

Comment: Which extension are you using for EJS support?

Comment: what is the TextMate scope of the red character